# Pause button pauses even when scroll function is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been able to make the video pause and play on scroll when it passes a specific pixel height. But my problem now is that the code I've written automaticly makes it play on any scroll when it's more than 13500px from the top. I am wondering if you can make it so that when you pause by the videos own cotrols button that it wont play even if you scorll. Because now it plays even if you've paused the video.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

                $(window).scroll(function() {

                    var vid = document.getElementById("video_1");

                        if($(document).scrollTop() > 13500) { 

                            vid.play(); 

                        }

                        else {



                         vid.pause(); 
                        }

                });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have listen for 'pause' and 'play' events of the video by the user. SO you can maintain a state whether user paused it or not. following code will do the trick.

```
var isPaused = false;
var vid;
$(document).ready(function() {
          vid = document.getElementById("video_1");
          vid.onpause = function() {
             isPaused = true;
          };
          vid.onplaying = function() {
             isPaused = false;
          }
                $(window).scroll(function() {



                        if($(document).scrollTop() > 13500 && !isPaused) { 

                            vid.play(); 

                        }

                        else {



                         vid.pause();
                         isPaused = true;
                        }

                });
        });
```

Comment: Ohh damn! Thank you so much! I'm totaly new with coding so I'm learning but your answer made it work! Thank you again!

Comment: @Rob Can you please accept the answer as correct, if it worked for you. Thanks